# Pytest fixture not found due to missing test data configured via TEST_DATA_DIR

Tags: python, debugging, testing, pytest

I am trying to run the test but I am running into an error and am a little confused as to how I could fix it. All the test take in a directory as a parameter, but since I haven't given it the parameter I am getting this error:

```
  E       fixture 'shared_datadir' not found
```

So I was simply going to add a fixture, but then I noticed the former developer had the following code in the init.py of the test directory:

```
from pathlib import Path


TEST_DATA_DIR = Path("<old path to experiment data>")
```

So, my question if there is how could I change this to the directory with my test data and have all the tests run? Below is an example of one of the tests if it helps:

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def paired_imgs(self, shared_datadir):

    return pio.load_tiff_as_hyperstack(
        (
            shared_datadir
            / "experiments"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47.tif"
        ),
        manual_metadata=(
            shared_datadir
            / "experiments"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47-frame_map.csv"
        ),
        mvmt_metadata=(
            shared_datadir
            / "experiments"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47"
            / "2017_02_22-HD233_SAY47-mvmt.csv"
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Are you using `pytest-datadir`? If yes, maybe this doc can help https://pypi.org/project/pytest-datadir/ as it describes about usage of the fixture `shared_datadir`.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first big project I am working on so I had/have no experience with pytest and big project tools in general haha